# on mousehover Show and hide div in Angular 2/ 4

Tags: angular

**show and hide a div on mouse hover using Angular2, how can we show and hide a div on mouse-hover in Angular2.**

Comment: Why not use CSS display proprety?

Comment: @JuniorGantin why to use CSS when angular provides events for the same

Answer (score 2):

```
<div (mouseover)="show = true" (mouseout)="show = false">Hello DIV</div>

<div *ngIf='show'>DIV to show/hide</div>
```

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dy2ocv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)